# paintComponent is not working java,

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

java swing,paintComponent
in the following code ,it is executing but the function paintComponent is not working so what is the reason to it . I m new to java so make these mistakes.

```
package practice;

    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    public class gui extends JPanel implements ActionListener  
    {
    JFrame frame;
    JButton button;
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
    public void go()
    {
        frame=new JFrame();
        button=new JButton("click me");
        frame.getContentPane().add(button);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(2000,2000);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

    gui g=new gui();
    g.go();

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {

        button.setText("mmmmm");
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 5):

You never add a gui instance to the JFrame, so the JPanel is not displayed. You create a `new gui()` object within the main method, but you never add this object to the JFrame. An equivalent bit would be  to add `this` to the JFrame within your `go()` method. You also need to add the JButton to `this`, not to the JFrame. A JPanel has to be added to a top-level window in order for it to be visualized. It won't magically appear.

For example:

```
public void go()
{
    frame=new JFrame();
    button=new JButton("click me");

    // frame.getContentPane().add(button); // !! Nope

    this.add(button);  // !! add button to the JPanel
    frame.getContentPane().add(this); // !! add the JPanel to the JFrame

    button.addActionListener(this);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(2000,2000);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Also, you should be overriding paintComponent, not paint. But having said that, to paint the background of a JPanel black, all you need is to call `setBackground(Color.BLACK)` wherever you set up the JPanel: For example:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Gui extends JPanel {
    private static final int PREF_W = 800;
    private static final int PREF_H = 650;
    private JButton button = new JButton(new ButtonAction("Click Me"));

    public Gui() {
        add(button);
        setBackground(Color.BLACK); // now no need to override paint/paintComponent
    }

    @Override
    // to make GUI bigger
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    // @Override  // no longer needed
    // protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    //     super.paintComponent(g);
    //     g.setColor(Color.black);
    //     g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    // }

    // better than having the GUI class implement ActionListener:
    private class ButtonAction extends AbstractAction {
        public ButtonAction(String name) {
            super(name);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            putValue(NAME, "mmmmmmm");
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        Gui mainPanel = new Gui();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Gui");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Also as side recommendations and to help us now and to help yourself in the future, please edit your code and change your variable names to conform with Java naming conventions: class names all start with an upper-case letter and method/variable names with a lower-case letter. Also fields should be private for the most part.

Comment: I tried with paintComponent also,but its not working.
is their any bug in calling or any other method?

Comment: "You never add a gui instance to the JFrame, so the JPanel is not displayed. Also, you should be overriding paintComponent, not paint." can u explain these lines a little brief?

Comment: @jatin5676: it's just like I stated: you create a `new gui()` object within the main method, but you never add this object to the JFrame. A JPanel has to be added to a top-level window in order for it to be visualized. It won't magically appear. Please see edit to answer to see better code for doing this.

Comment: @jatin5676: An equivalent bit would be  to add `this` to the JFrame within your `go()` method. You also need to add the JButton to `this`, not to the JFrame. i.e., `this.add(button);` and `frame.add(this);`

Comment: @jatin5676: see additional info in edits to answer please.